# How to express atomic states 1S, 1D, 3P in terms of spherical harmonics or cubic harmonics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, quantum-chemistry

Textbook state that, because of Pauli principle and anti-symmetry of wave-function, only 1S, 3P, 1D with totally $C_6^2=15$ states are allowed for 2 electrons $np^2$ state. My question is how to express these states in terms of spherical harmonics or cubic harmonics? I only know it should have the form of direct product of orbital and spin wave-function with one being symmetric and the other anti-symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found in Clebsch–Gordan coefficients
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#_j1_=_1,_j2_=_1

$
|^{1}S\rangle =|2,0,0;0,0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left[|1,-1\rangle-|0,0\rangle+|-1,1\rangle\right]|s\rangle \\
|^{1}D_{2}\rangle =|2,2,0;2,0\rangle=|1,1\rangle|s\rangle \\
|^{1}D_{1}\rangle =|2,2,0;1,0\rangle=\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}\left[|1,0\rangle+|0,1\rangle\right]|s\rangle \\
|^{1}D_{0}\rangle =|2,2,0;0,0\rangle=\frac{1} {\sqrt{6}}\left[|1,-1\rangle+2|0,0\rangle+|-1,1\rangle\right]|s\rangle \\
|^{1}D_{-1}\rangle =|2,2,0;-1,0\rangle=\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}\left[|-1,0\rangle+|0,-1\rangle\right]|s\rangle \\
|^{1}D_{-2}\rangle =|2,2,0;-2,0\rangle=|-1,-1\rangle|s\rangle \\
|^{3}P_{1}\rangle =|2,1,1;1,M_{S}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[|1,0\rangle-|0,1\rangle\right]|t_{M_{S}}\rangle \\
|^{3}P_{0}\rangle =|2,1,1;0,M_{S}\rangle=\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}\left[|1,-1\rangle-|-1,1\rangle\right]|t_{M_{S}}\rangle \\
|^{3}P_{-1}\rangle =|2,1,1;-1,M_{S}\rangle=\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}}\left[|0,-1\rangle-|-1,0\rangle\right]|t_{M_{S}}\rangle 
$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).